# Css to make button Caption Bold

Tags: css

I want to make the button caption bold. But it should not affect the width of the button. i tried font-weight it changes the width of the button.

```
<input type="button" style="width:10px" class="buttonEnabled">
<input type="button" style="width:20px" class="buttonEnabled">
    .buttonEnabled:hover {
    font-weight:bold;
    }
```

Comment: set the width of the button too

Comment: i cant do so i have many buttons with different size. using this class in a seprate css file

Comment: `width= "10px"` I don't think that is valid. Since you are not setting a default width, it will be created using a browser set width and then expand it when font-weight is increased.

Comment: `style="width: 10px"` is valid though. Defining such style properties in the CSS instead of HTML is a best practice in my opinion though.

Comment: sorry leroydev thanks for ur comment i have changed it

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to fix widths or you have multiple width inputs, then you could simulate a *faux* bolder text by using `text-shadow` only on `hover`.

Use `0` for x and y offsets to make the shadow outline the text. Tweak the color to reduce or increase the impact.

**Example Snippet:**

```css
.buttonEnabled:hover { text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #333; }
```

```html
<input type="button" class="buttonEnabled" value="Submit">
```

**Edit:** This works in all modern browsers, but will not work with IE < 10.

For old IE, you could use the `shadow filter` with standard `text-shadow` as the last rule. Something like this:

```
.buttonEnabled:hover { 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(
    color=#333,direction=0,strength=1
  );
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #333; 
}
```

I haven't tested it though. You may need to tweak it out. More details of this legacy rule is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks but i think it doesnt support in earlier ie 8 versions. have any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (set a `min-width`):

**CSS**

```
  .buttonEnabled{
    min-width: 100px;
    }

 .buttonEnabled:hover {
    font-weight:bold;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" class="buttonEnabled" value="teste">
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/71/)**

Comment: And what about the width on hover?

Comment: @devpro, is the same witdh as normal...on hover don´t mess with the width

Comment: @GaneshNB , no need to specify the width on hover...it as already in the normal state a min-width

Comment: thanks. u r correct but it doesnt helps me. since i'm using in large application where i may need to use button with higher and smaller width .i cant use a fixed size to all.